# Adding Magento attributes and attribute-sets programmatically

Tags: magento, attributes, set

Adding attributes to Magento via code is very obscure. Are there any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can find the answer to your questions in this code example:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/programmatically_adding_attributes_and_attribute_sets